# Rotate image 360° every .75 seconds on Loop JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate.css

I need to get a JS script to get this center arrow image (loading.svg) to rotate 360 degrees every .75 seconds on a continuous loop. Here is the button I'm talking about.

http://royalidea.com/happyname/pending.html

It would been to be a class so that several of these icons could be rotating simultaneously - several loading items at time...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: why not animated gif? I assume this is place holder while images load, yes?

Comment: It's a filler button while we run scripts and pull data into the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is CSS answer:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h6v0rhcn/)

```
.loading_arrow {
    width: 32px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 42%;
    -webkit-animation: rotation .75s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: rotation .75s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: rotation .75s infinite linear;
    animation: rotation .75s infinite linear;
}
body {
    background-color:#000;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS solution which will spin 360deg every 0.75s with a 0.75s delay. If you want the delay to be longer or shorter, just play with the 50% portion of `50%, 100%` and adjust the `animation` time accordingly.

```
img.loading_arrow {
    -webkit-animation: spin_delay 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: spin_delay 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin_delay {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
  }

  50%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin_delay {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
  }

  50%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
  }
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3na66ug3/

Comment: And if you don't want the delay, just remove the `50%, ` from both keyframes, and lower the timing. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3na66ug3/1/))

Comment: Nice. So will the icon animate by adding the above code to the style.css file?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Rotate HTML elements by mouse in JavaScript - Propeller.js</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example/css/turbine.css">
</head>
<body>
<img id="turbine" src="example/img/turbine.png" onmousedown="showLibraryInfo()" ontouchstart="showLibraryInfo()">

<div class="arrow">
    <img src="example/img/arrow.png">

    <p>
        Drag or swipe propeller
    </p>
</div>
<script src="src/propeller.js"></script>
<script>
    new Propeller(document.getElementById('turbine'), {inertia: 0.99});

    function showLibraryInfo() {
        if (window.libInfoShown !== true) {
            var windStuff = document.getElementsByClassName('wind');
            var libStuff = document.getElementsByClassName('propeller');
            for (var i = 0; i < windStuff.length; i++) {
                var obj = windStuff[i];
                obj.style.display = 'none';
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < libStuff.length; i++) {
                var obj = libStuff[i];
                obj.style.display = 'inline-block';
            }
            window.libInfoShown = true;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size:0.8em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial";
    color: #ffffff;
}

#turbine {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 99;
}

.turbine {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.arrow {
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Demo: http://pixelscommander.com/polygon/propeller/example/jquerygrid.html#.VAX2ASiaWJI
Source: http://www.techrecite.com/rotate-image-photo-or-object-around-its-axis-using-javascript-animation/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an animated gif as well, however, you can do it with JS like this:

```
$(function() {
    var loading = $('.loading_arrow'),
        degree = 0,
        timer;

    function rotate() {    
        loading.css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            ++degree;
            rotate();
        },5); //lower this to increase speed
    }

    rotate();
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLbgfv5o/)

Comment: This seems to work great for animating the rotation but how can I make it considerably faster? See here:

http://royalidea.com/happyname/

The arrow is rotating at the speed set to 0 but is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Currently, the degree is only being incremented by 1 each time, to make it rotate faster you can change the degree to increment by 5 each time by changing the line that says `++degree;` to `degree = degree+5;` or whatever you want it to increment by.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS animations:

```
@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
} 

@keyframes loader {
    from {transform: rotate(0);}
    to {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}

img {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;   
    -webkit-animation: loader 1s infinite linear;
    animation: loader 1s infinite linear;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fhez3fsm/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure CSS solution with a jsFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cay3j79t/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="loading" src="http://royalidea.com/happyname/img/loading.svg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background-color: blue;
}

.loading {
    -webkit-animation: cycle 0.75s infinite linear;
    animation: cycle 0.75s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
    from {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes cycle {
    from {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```